# Vb dot net copy file to network share that is password protected

Tags: mysql, vb.net, blob

I am using vb.net to create an app and now I want the users to upload scanned images or documents into the database and retrieve it but I have tried searching a lot of forums but have not yet got any solution that works.

Comment: @Renat the link you posted is on php but i am programming in vb.net with mysql as my database

Comment: https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiBhriXkPHkAhXR0KQKHfXUA38QwqsBMAB6BAgJEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DVL-GzIgL7Pg&usg=AOvVaw2Y2UPDVZyQI7PIHNJTPH2j

Comment: I was about to copy your code to see what was wrong and then I saw that there was none. Please include your best attempt by clicking the edit link below your question and add your code, formatted as code.

Comment: @Mary I have switched to an alternative method by inserting the file path into the database and then using System.IO.File.Copy command to copy the file to a networkhsare share on my LAN. The problem i am having now is this: due to user account password on the server, i get username/password error when trying to upload any file again.

Comment: Pleas edit the question and show the code that is causing the error. How are you collecting the username and password? Where are you sending it to the server? Is the password stored as plain text?

Comment: @Mary I dont know how to send the username and password along with the command.The server is just a computer whose hard-drive i have shared on the LAN.  This is the code                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", "use Z: \\SHADOW-PC\Users\ /USER:shadow hacker")
System.IO.File.Copy(Button6.Text, "\\SHADOW-PC\Users\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Button6.Text), True)
This is the link to the image of the program i am building.There you will see what i am trying to do.https://ibb.co/YZzTTHx

Comment: Please don't post code over a single simple line in comments. It is unreadable. You need to click the edit link below your question and add it there. You need to look at ADO.net to find out how to add data to a database.